# Stop Float value rounding off in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have to prevent the value from rounding off after the decimal.

Here is the code I use :

```
NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
nf.positiveFormat = @"0.###";      
NSString* trimmedValue = [nf stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[exRateLabel doubleValue]*amount]];
trimmedValue = [trimmedValue substringToIndex:[trimmedValue length]-1];
```

In this case, if I multiply **1000 * 50.1234** I'm getting **50123.3984**, but it should be **50123.4**.

```
NSLog(@".2f",50.1234*1000);
```

For this case it's showing the correct value but for

```
NSLog(@".2f",50.1234*123);
```

it is rounding off the actual value, which is **6165.1782**, to **6165.18**.

Comment: multiply 10000etc, save to integer. divide by same 1000etc

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks for reply but for 4999*50.1234 i'm getting 250566.891

Comment: first multiply 50.1234 by 1000s, to round of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use double instead of float and a proper rounding rule:

```
NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.positiveFormat = @"0.###";
nf.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor;
NSString* trimmedValue = [nf stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:50.1234*123]];
NSLog(@"trimmedValue: %@", trimmedValue);
```

And the result is:

```
trimmedValue: 6165.178
```

Comment: Hi 4999*50.1234 in this case i'm getting 250566.88 instead of 250566.87

Comment: 250566.8766 rounds to 250566.88

Comment: i don't want to round i need to display only .87 but it displaying .88

Answer (score 2):

If the mathematics is required to be precise, I'd suggest using an NSDecimalNumber.

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithMantissa:501234 exponent:-4 isNegative:NO]];  
NSDecimalNumber *answer = [self multiplyDecimalNumber:myNumber with:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1000 exponent:0 isNegative:NO];  
NSLog(@"Answer: %g", floor([answer doubleValue]));
```

I made  a quick wrapper for the multiplication, I never wanted an exception, your needs may be different:

```
-(NSDecimalNumber *) multiplyDecimalNumber:(NSDecimalNumber *) lhs with:(NSDecimalNumber *) rhs {  
    NSDecimalNumberHandler *handler = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:NSDecimalNoScale raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];  
    return [lhs decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:rhs withBehavior:handler];  
}
```

Comment: hi its converting perfectly but while i'm displaying in label as .2f is rounding again. That is my issue....

Comment: Then it seems like you're just not happy with the rounding.  If that's the case, you could do something like:   `floor((50.1234 * 123) * 100) / 100`  - this will remove any precision after the second decimal place.  Edit - Manu's post from ~50 minutes ago contains a convenience functions, if this is the fix you're looking for, I would suggest awarding Manu with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

First, I believe you have a typo - you're missing the `%`.

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", 50.1234*1000); // same as @"%.2f", 50,123.4 = @"50123.4"
```

the math leaves you with a clean 1/10th, even though you are asking for 2 decimal places to be printed.

```
NSLog(@"%.2f",50.1234*123); // same as @"%.2f", 5,161.1782 = @"5161.18"
```

you are asking for two decimal numbers and rounding up is the default behavior.

It sounds like the formatting you actually want to use is:

```
NSLog(@"%.1f", number);
```

or if you want a forced, zero-padded two digits, use

```
NSLog(@"%.02", number); // first case would come out @"50123.40"
```

this will force all trailing zeros to be printed

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using a 'double' representation, cast the number to a float or you can use your own policy for truncation using functions like:

```
float roundUp (float value, int digits) {

    int mod = pow(10, digits);

    float roundedUp = value;
    if (mod != 0) {
        roundedUp = ceilf(value * mod) / mod;
    }

    return roundedUp;
}

float roundDown (float value, int digits) {

    int mod = pow(10, digits);

    float roundedDown = value;
    if (mod != 0) {
       roundedDown = floorf(value * mod) / mod;
    }

    return roundedDown;
}

float nearestf (float value, int digits) {

    int mod = pow(10, digits);

    float nearest = value;
    if (mod != 0) {
        nearest = floorf(value*mod + 0.5) / mod;
    }

    return nearest;
}
```

'roundUp' should be the one you need, or try with the more generic 'nearestf'

Answer (score 0):

For me it was requirement to show atleast two decimal and maximum decimal number.
Following code did worked for me.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
NSString *num = @"123456.019";
NSString *stringFromNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[numberFormatter numberFromString:num]];
NSLog(@"check this %@", stringFromNumber);
```